# Как сделать http запрос данного типа на python?

Tags: python, http, httpclient

```
GET /api/v1/auth HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic <encoded_auth>
User-Agent: <app>/<app-version> <os>[ <os-version>]
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой `requests` (она не из стандартной библиотеки и ее нужно установить)

```py
import requests


url = "https://orioks.miet.ru/api/v1/auth"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic ODIxMTcwODpBZHZpY2VtaWV0dXNlcnM0Cg==",
    "User-Agent": "edubot/0.1 Windows NT 10.0"
}

auth = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(auth)
```

Comment: Я собственно так и сделал,но выдает ошибку.Я все перепробывал,поэтому пришел сюда

Comment: from json import load
import requests
from requests.models import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "https://orioks.miet.ru/api/v1/auth" 

config = {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Authorization": "ODIxMTcwODpBZHZpY2VtaWV0dXNlcnM0Cg==",
    "User-Agent": "edubot/0.1 Windows NT 10.0"
}
auth = requests.get(url,headers=config)

print(auth)

Comment: выдает <Response [400]>

Comment: @Valera21 ну так 400 это значит, что не так с вашими параметрами. Я же не знаю какие параметры сервер ожидает. Запрос вы сделали, а вопрос ваш был именно про это.

Comment: так вроде все  передал,поидее он должен вернуть токен

Comment: https://orioks.gitlab.io/student-api/auth.html#

Comment: @Valera21 судя по вашему примеру вы перед токеном не ставите слово `Basic`. Я добавил в ответ именно ваш пример, просто добавил это слово. Мне возвращает 403, что означает, что токен неверный. Подставьте верный токен и все заведется.